# Installing tar.gz file which has no configure, install, and readme file

Tags: software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I have downloaded the latest version of Pycharm for using Python programming language called pycharm-community-4.5.3.tar.gz from the website: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/ The earlier Pycharm 5.4.2 is running fine in this computer, but this new 4.5.3 has no `configure` or `install` or `readme.txt` files. I extracted the tar-file but it had no `configure` file or `install` file or any readme files. I also copied the tar.gz file from Downloads to /usr/local/src and extracted the file there. When I type `./configure` I get an error:

> ./configure: No such file or directory

Also, I tried the `make` command and it gave an error:

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

I am wondering how to install this program. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You need a configure file to run `./configure`. Likewise you need a Makefile to run make. There are some other tools that build these that are pretty common, but what is almost universal is that there is a README or INSTALL or both text file in the source. Open that with your favorite text editor and it should tell you how to build and install the software.

Answer (score 4):

The `./configure` and `make` steps that you are referring to are only necessary when software is supplied as source code. In the case of `pycharm`, it is provided as a pre-built executable.

The [jetbrains website](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) includes a link to the following [installation instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/installation_instructions.jsp?os=linux)

> ## Installation Instructions
>
> - Copy the pycharm-*.tar.gz to the desired installation location (make
>     sure you have rw permissions for that directory)
> - Unpack the pycharm-*.tar.gz using the following command: tar xfz pycharm-*.tar.gz
> - Remove the pycharm-*.tar.gz to save disk space (optional)
> - Run pycharm.sh from the bin subdirectory